# Where is created the fourth object eligible to GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

```
01 class Account { Long acctNum, password;}
02 public class Banker {
03  public static void main(String[] args){
04      new Banker().go(); //created object
05      //Here there are 4 objects eligible to GC
06  }
07  void go(){
08      Account a1 = new Account(); //created object
09      a1.acctNum = new Long("1024"); //created object
10      Account a2 = a1;
11      Account a3 = a2;
12      a3.password = a1.acctNum.longValue();
13      a2.password = 4455L;
14  }
15 }
```

In line 13 is created a long and when autobox make the wrapper Long, could be the forth object created?

Are the following lines also creating objects?

```
long l = 4455L;
long m = 4455;
long n = 4455l;
```

Comment: what do you mean by _In line 13 is created a long and when autobox make the wrapper Long, could be the object created?_

Answer (score 2):

```
Long l = 4455L;
```

That autoboxes and creates object (just like `a2.password = 4455L;` does). W

hile the following doesn't (because the type is primitive so, there's no need to autobox)

```
long l = 4455L;
```

Comment: also the primitive datatype long is stored in stack and Long is stored on heap

Comment: @BhavikShah: Actually you are right. How I look at it is not whether is is primitive/object. Actually it's the variable that is stored in the stack, which in the case of primitive happens to be it's value and reference in the case ref-type. So, you are also right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, line 13 does create a new Long by autoboxing. The other 3 lines (l,m,n) do not create objects because they are primitives.

So your 4 objects are Banker, Account and the two Longs.